# How to trigger mouseover function on an element when not really mouseovered

Tags: jquery, mouseover

In jQuery, is it possible for an element to act like it is mouseovered automatically when the page is loading, when it is not really mouseovered? I mean, I won't put my pointer on the desired element for it to do what it would do if I put.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger an event.

```
$('#foo').trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call the handler directly

```
$('abc').mouseover();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the desired action in the `document.ready` function as that is when you actually want the action, not on a mouse-over that doesn't happen.