# Leaflet foreach feature auto trigger mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I am stuck with a situation where I have to create a dashboard application similar to [ChoroplethExample](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html). But the only problem is I have to iterate between all states(Features in [geoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js)) and pause for like 3 seconds in every iteration.

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350603/how-to-trigger-mouseover-function-on-an-element-when-not-really-mouseovered) where mouseover trigger example is given. But how can we use it for this case.

Below is the function that needs to be fired in every iteration:
[LeafletExample](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html#adding-interaction)

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
var layer = e.target;

layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
});

if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
    layer.bringToFront();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `L.GeoJSON`'s `eachLayer` method to iterate over the layers and then use `highlightFeature` method on the current layer and `resetHighlight` method on the previous layer (if any).

Remove current interaction:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        //mouseover: highlightFeature,
        //mouseout: resetHighlight,
        //click: zoomToFeature
    });
}
```

Add iterator:

```
// Variables for storing currently highlighted feature and delay amount
var highlight, delay = 0;

// Iterate over each layer in the geojsonlayer
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {

    // Mimick event object because highlightFeature and resetHighlight
    // expect an object with the layer as target property
    layer = {'target': layer};

    // Up the delay amount
    delay = delay + 3000;

    setTimeout(function() {

        // Check if there is a highlight, if so reset
        if (highlight) {
            resetHighlight(highlight);
        }

        // Highlight current and store
        highlightFeature(layer);
        highlight = layer;

    }, delay);
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QD2uHv?p=preview

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but there is a slight thing that I want to highlight one state at a time similar to the example in leaflet site where you hover and relevant data comes in info tab. I just want to emulate all states but one a time.

Comment: Ok, understood, sorry for the misunderstanding, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much.